# Worst Case Time Complexity of Stream Filter and Sort

Tags: java, performance, sorting, time-complexity, java-stream

As I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684200/time-complexity-of-stream-filter), the time complexity of filter in the following code is O(n).

```
List<Listing> Listings = new ArrayList<>();
Listings.add(listing1);
Listings.add(listing2);
...
...
...

Listing listing = listings.stream()
                .filter(l -> l.getVin() == 456)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Is the time complexity still O(n) as I chain other functions to the stream like I have done so with sorted (below)?**

```
List<Listing> Listings = new ArrayList<>();
Listings.add(listing1);
Listings.add(listing2);
...
...
...

Listing listing = listings.stream()
                .filter(l -> l.getVin() == 456)
                .sorted((a, b) -> // some comparator here )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, constant factors get dropped from the O notation. If `x` is a constant (like 2, or 3), then `O(x*n)` = `O(n)`. That is, assuming each function you chain in is `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected that was the case. Will read the time complexity post you provided.

Comment: I would love to hear a follow up because you start with O(n) with the stream and filter and collect. However you are adding O(log n) for the sort. I am not a mathematician but would this be something like O(n) + O(log n)

Comment: In this case it's not that simple about constant, I think. The sort is after filter, so the complexity is not just about sort, but also about the number of `Listings` the filter get. If the number is a constant, the whole complexity would be O(n) as the filter.

Comment: Actually just thinking about it the sorted operation is a terminal operation so this will affect the original time of the algo. Meaning the sort has to internally collect all elements from the stream in order to sort them. I believe this makes it 0(n) in this case due to the fact that collect has an operation to accept a collection itself.